# External view html files in Angularjs Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please advice how to include(use) commonly used and shared between few projects html files.
so html files from external server needs to be included in Angularjs router.
Here is a short example of what i have and what i am trying to solve.
Now .html is in my project folder:

```
 .state('chatbase', {
            url: '/cn={cn}',
             onEnter: function ($stateParams, ParamsShareService) {
               ParamsShareService.updateCnValue($stateParams.cn);

            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/chat_wv1.html',
                    controller: 'ChatController'
                }

            }

             })
```

And i am trying to get them work like this.So i can share the structure for few projects.

```
 .state('chatbase', {
            url: '/cn={cn}',
             onEnter: function ($stateParams, ParamsShareService) {
               ParamsShareService.updateCnValue($stateParams.cn);

            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'https://my-website/views/chat_wv1.html',
                    controller: 'ChatController'
                }

            }

             })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you implemented it will not work.

`templateUrl` support explicit path to your project or String.

HTML is a static file with static content. However calling file from `HTTP` means get file content by using HTTP protocol - different flow and `templateUrl` doesn't support this way.

Further, Angular state is loaded before any controller and I believe `templateUrl: 'views/chat_wv1.html',` is what we have today.

You can try this approach (but its a bit complicated):

1) you can load some *teplate.html*

```
views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/teplate.html',
                controller: 'ChatController'
            }
        }
```

2) The `teplate.html` will be bind to some Controller that will load HTML **content** from server and you can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) + [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to achieve what you look for

Comment: Thank you, what about this thing  ` $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'https://website/view.html'
    ]);`

Comment: Here is the link, or am i missing something?  https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_include_crossdomain

Comment: @Beny well, its not related to `state` -> `templateUrl`

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice, i will mark you answer as correct.And will take a look at compile.Thank you